# Lie Algebra: Vector subspace is an ideal of its normalizer

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $S$ be a vector subspace of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$.

Is $S$ an ideal of the normalizer $N_\mathfrak{g}(S)$, I would say yes since:

$\forall n\in N_\mathfrak{g}(S), [n,S]\subseteq S\implies [N_\mathfrak{g}(S),S]\subseteq S$ which is the definition of an ideal right?

Comment: Thanks @duffymo. [I didn't know that](http://www.businesswritingblog.com/business_writing/2006/05/its_its_or_its_.html) Which is pretty bad

Comment: Do you have any doubt about your argument ? If yes, could you say what exactly is doubtful ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Since $S$ isn't a subalgebra it shouldn't work, since $i$ is an ideal of $g$ $\implies$ $i$ is a subalgebra of $g$

But here that isn't the case by assumption, but I can't see why the subalgebra condition is needed.

$S$ is not necessarily contained in the normaliser, but $[N_\mathfrak{g}(S),S]\subseteq S$ seems to be true?

Comment: @Lie Algebra - a small thing.  Your mathematics are most impressive.  No worries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normalizer of a subspace $S$ in $\mathfrak{g}$ is the largest subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$ containing $S$ as an ideal. Here "containing" means that
$S\subseteq N_{\mathfrak{g}}(S)$, i.e., that $[S,S]\subseteq S$. So $S$ is a subalgebra, and of course then also an ideal, as you have shown.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense, I am so silly.

Comment: Oh, don't worry. I have to concentrate on this each time again.